# Where to find a package version history?

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management

For example, I want to find out when linux-image-virtual-hwe-20.04 start offering the 5.8 kernel.
From the changelog, it looks like 14 Jun 2020, which doesn't quite match my memory.
`apt changelog linux-image-virtual-hwe-20.04`

```
linux-meta-5.8 (5.8.0.0.0) groovy; urgency=medium

  * Empty entry.

 -- Seth Forshee <seth.forshee@canonical.com>  Sun, 14 Jun 2020 22:36:18 -0500
```

For this specific question, I would like to know it became stable before or after or at the same time as 20.04.2. But it would be great if there was a common approach for all packages.

Comment: The 5.8 kernel was from 20.10 (*groovy*) during the development stage, so 14-June-2020 seems appropriate to me; it would likely hit my box 3-6 days after that (I'm on *kinetic* currently or on the *development* release).  I could likely confirm when it was installed in my logs, just don't see a need.  Don't forget 20.04 doesn't get it until some time after 20.10 is released (when 20.04.2 starts rolling out, like 20.04.5 is currently rolling out now).   FYI Packages need to be changed, built & get out; I want a package that was changed this morning (*my local time*) but it's currently -proposed

Comment: As for your additional question; have a look at the *focal* release (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseSchedule) you'll note 20.04.5 is due to be released September 1, however the 5.15 kernel stack from 20.04.5 has already rolled out, as those changes are rolling out currently. The release date refers to the ISO release date; with installed systems getting it weeks before hand (as is normal).  The kernel became *stable* under the *groovy* cycle; the *most stable* kernel for 20.04 is the GA kernel, HWE kernel stack changes during it's life (using *stable* kernels from later releases)

Comment: @guiverc Thanks a lot, I did upgrade to 5.15 today, but again I don't know exactly when 5.15 was available.

Comment: You can look at the same changelog you did before most likely; eg. https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-meta_5.15.0.27.30/changelog which has a date of 17-Sept-2021, and again I likely got it on this box a number of days after that (new *upgraded* kernel stack is usually more than the 3-6 days I said before).  Also note:  you said you got 5.15 today?  Do you use your system daily? upgrade often? as I noted 5.15 roll out to *focal* more than a week ago if I recall correctly (I'm not using *focal* currently so can't check, but I also upgrade 3 times a day & look)

Comment: @guiverc I usually check for updates weekly or longer. That's my point. Even if I could get the exact time of 5.15 by checking updates every minute, I couldn't travel back to 2020 to monitor the arrival of 5.8

Comment: The file I mentioned before shows 5.15.0.18.18 kernel as being dated `21-Jan-2022 17:17 +0100`,  that kernel was installed on my system in my `apt` log at `Start-Date: 2022-01-28  12:19:30` because `Commandline: apt full-upgrade` so I'd use that date.   I originally said 3-6 days if you read back.. It's not far off !   (*I don't recall what I was doing on 27-29 Jan-2022 to be more accurate.. packages need time to build, test, propagate etc.. eg. the package edited earlier today is available in -proposed but I'm happy to wait for it for another day!  on Wed I'll force it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note:  this answer is mostly copied from comments & further questions*

The 5.8 kernel was from 20.10 (*groovy*) during the development stage, so 14-June-2020 seems appropriate to me; it would likely hit my box 3-6 days after that (I'm on *kinetic* currently or on the development release).

I could likely confirm when it was installed in my logs, I just don't see a need.

Don't forget 20.04 doesn't get it until some time after 20.10 is released (when 20.04.2 starts rolling out, like 20.04.5 is currently rolling out now). FYI Packages need to be changed, built & get out; I want a package that was changed this morning (my local time) but it's currently *-proposed*

As for your additional question; have a look at the focal release (https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-meta_5.15.0.27.30/changelog) you'll note 20.04.5 is due to be released September 1, however the 5.15 kernel stack from 20.04.5 has already rolled out, as those changes are rolling out currently.

The release date refers to the ISO release date; with installed systems getting it weeks before hand (as is normal). The kernel became stable under the *groovy* cycle; the most stable kernel for 20.04 is the GA kernel, HWE kernel stack changes during it's life (using *stable* kernels from later releases)

You can look at the same changelog you did before most likely; eg. https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-meta_5.15.0.27.30/changelog which has a date of 17-Sept-2021, and again I likely got it on this box a number of days after that (new upgraded kernel stack is usually more than the 3-6 days I said before). Also note: you said you got 5.15 today? Do you use your system daily? upgrade often? as I noted 5.15 roll out to focal more than a week ago if I recall correctly (I'm not using focal currently so can't check, but I also upgrade 3 times a day & look)

The file I mentioned before shows **5.15.0.18.18 kernel** as being dated `21-Jan-2022 17:17 +0100`,

```
linux-meta (5.15.0.18.18) jammy; urgency=medium

  * Bump ABI 5.15.0-18

 -- Andrea Righi <andrea.righi@canonical.com>  Fri, 21 Jan 2022 15:21:25 +0100
```

that kernel was installed on my system in my `apt` log at `Start-Date: 2022-01-28  12:19:30` because `Commandline: apt full-upgrade` so I'd use that date.

```
Start-Date: 2022-01-28  12:19:30
Commandline: apt full-upgrade
Requested-By: guiverc (1000)
Install: linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-18-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-18.18, automatic), linux-image-5.15.0-18-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-18.18, automatic), linux-tools-5.15.0-18-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-18.18, automatic), linux-tools-5.15.0-18:amd64 (5.15.0-18.18, automatic), linux-headers-5.15.0-18:amd64 (5.15.0-18.18, automatic), linux-headers-5.15.0-18-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-18.18, automatic), linux-modules-5.15.0-18-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-18.18, automatic)
```

I originally said 3-6 days if you read back.. It's not far off !   (*I don't recall what I was doing on 26-29th Jan-2022 to be more accurate, I will say I don't have my system auto-update so  I can monitor what packages upgrade; for QA purposes*).  Also note need time to build, test, propagate etc (*the date from Andrea is for the edit*).. eg. the package edited earlier today is available in *-proposed* but I'm happy to wait for it for another day!  (*on Wednesday I may force it as I've got other things I will do in the meantime*)

Comment: FYI:  The 3-6 days is my *general rule of thumb*,  it's less for smaller/simpler packages (eg. *faster for say a package containing wallpapers*) and longer for more complex packages where I consider a kernel as being complex (*ie. many [complex] packages are involved*)

Answer (score 1):

You find it exactly where you found it. But it doesn't mean that that package was moved to stable repositories exactly at the same day.

Comment: Isn't there a way to know when it's stable?

Comment: What do you mean by "became stable'?

Comment: A regular user with focal and focal-updates repo will receive this update.

Comment: There may be some repository logs.